# implementing a comparable interface in java

Tags: java, comparable

I want my class to implement the `Comparable` interface. Which of the following approaches is correct

Option 1:

```
public Myclass implements Comparable<MyClass>{

  public int compareTo(MyClass o){
   //impl here
  }

}
```

Option 2:

```
public Myclass implements Comparable{

  public int compareTo(Object o){
     //check if o  instance of my class
     //impl here
  }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**. The answer is in the comments of the second snippet. You would avoid explicit type casting.

Option 1 takes advantage of Java Generics. Here is a link to the tutorial on [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'd hesitate to call one "correct" and the other "incorrect," but option 1 seems "better."  Option 1 uses generics, and one of the primary benefits of generics is to avoid doing the awkward `instanceof` followed by a cast from Option 2.  However, generics were not originally part of Java, so some legacy code still uses the Option 2 approach.